# Django 2: project root url namespace not working

Tags: django, url

I have the following url patters in the project root's `urls.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('main/', include('main.urls', namespace='main')),
]
```

But django complains with the following message:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name is not supported. Set the app_name attribute in the included module, or pass a 2-tuple containing the list of patterns and app_name instead.
```

According Django's [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/), the pattern of 'main' should be correct. What's the problem?

Comment: Did you try doing what it says, and setting the app_name attribute in the included module?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add `app_name = 'main'` to the main.urls file. See example and description [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/#id5).

Comment: Question: how do I `pass a 2-tuple containing the list of patterns and app_name instead`?

Comment: @SugarTang something like this `include((pattern_list, app_name), namespace=None)`. More details: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/#include